# What is the name and schema of the 5-pin connector

Tags: identification, connector, cables

I have on my ebike this type of connector. Do you know what is the name and schema of it?

Edit1:  The eBike is LeaderFox 2020 Altar. The cable is from TFT 860c display to the Bafang M500 engine.

[image]

Comment: What documentation does the eBike supplier provide that might be useful?

Comment: There is no info about this connector

Comment: You forgot to tell us the brand of bike, the brand of the electronics kit and what part of the bike the connector is for. Saddle temperature sensing? Hit the [edit] link below your question ...

Comment: @Transistor The eBike is LeaderFox 2020 Altar. The cable is from TFT 860c display to the Bafang M500 engine.

Answer (score 3):

It is a higo Mini F cable. have the same on my leaderfox. The real issue is that displays are standard not manufactured with this type of cable but use Micro B instead. Been trying to find a replacement display for ages or an adapter cable.

Answer (score 1):

Following on @user257228's answer +1, it's a [A&C/Higo](https://www.ac-solutions.be/en/products/z209fgp00a01000/QB09K) (Belgian company) "Z509FG P 00 A3 1000", and you can find a cable [here](https://www.e-bike-technologies.de/index.php/en/connectors/connectors-signal/connectors-higo-mini-f-series/higo-s5-f-detail) for ~€5.

[image]